# Truncate text to a desired end word

Tags: php

So I want to truncate a very long text but the problem is that I don't want x number of word or characters. I want the text truncated when it reaches a special string like ###end### or something similar e.g. I want to set where exactly it ends.
edit: I know how to check the existences of the string I wasn't sure how to make the truncation

Comment: I would advise you to take a look at [this](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: strpos() will help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if string contains specific words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
$pos = strpos($mystring, "###end###");
$finalText = substr ( $mystring , 0 , $pos );
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a single call.  My answer assumes that the targeted substring will exist in the string.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cec957ba86dee500d3c10e8363e3f0d5843d2965))

```
$string='Here is a sample string.###end### I do not want to see any of this';
echo strstr($string,'###end###',true);  // 3rd parameter 'true' will extract everything before
```

Output:

```
Here is a sample string.
```

---

If you are uncertain if the substring will exist (and if it doesn't, you want the fullstring) this is a reliable method:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7acac82f956516614dd714854fa92ca02e80f86c))

```
$string='Here is a sample string.###end### I do not want to see any of this';
echo explode('###end###',$string,2)[0];  // 3rd parameter 2 will limit the number of elements produced to two
```

Output:

```
Here is a sample string.
```